# How can I run $scope functions from a templateUrl in a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Here's a plnkr to show you all the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/0EdLH3gGoUrWcQkOeukt (I tried to only show what's necessary but I want to show what's going on with task sorting because that is ultimately what I want to achieve)

I am able to run $scope functions in the controller if they are triggered from index.html but not from repeat.html (the templateUrl). @Kato has made it clear that I will need use a transclude but after trying for a while I cannot figure it out. Nothing seems to show up for me when I set transclude:true and add ng-transclude to the  in repeat.html.

```
//index.html
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <section>
    <form ng-submit="addTask(task); task.title=null">
      <input placeholder="Add Task" ng-model="task.title" />
    </form>
    <repeat-by-week collection="list"></repeat-by-week>
  </section>
</body>

//repeat.html (the templateUrl file) 
<ul class="tasks-list">
  <li ng-repeat="week in weeks">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="day in week.days">
        <h4>{{day.time | date:"MMMM dd'th'" }}</h4>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="task in day.items">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.complete" ng-change="isCompleteTask(task)">
            <input ng-model="task.title" ng-change="updateTask(task)">
            <button ng-click="deleteTask(task)">x</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>


   //the controller (I can access $scope.addTask but not update, delete, or complete)
   angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $firebase){
      var ref = new Firebase('https://plnkr.firebaseio.com/tasks');
      $scope.list = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

      $scope.addTask = function(newTask) {  
          $scope.list.$add({
            title: newTask.title,
            $priority: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
            complete: false,
            completeTime: '',
            createTime: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
          });
        };

      $scope.deleteTask = function(task){
          alert('delete task was clicked');
          $scope.list.$remove(task);
        };

        $scope.updateTask = function(task){
          $scope.list.$save(task);
        };

        $scope.isCompleteTask = function(task){
          if(task.completeTime){
            task.completeTime = '';
          } else{
            task.completeTime = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
          }
          $scope.list.$save(task);
        };  

    });

//the directive 
angular.module('app').directive('repeatByWeek', function($parse, $window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'repeat.html',
    scope: {
      'master': '=collection'
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      // get the global moment lib
      var moment = $window.moment;
      scope.weeks = [];
      updateList();

      // whenever the source collection changes, update our nested list
      scope.master.$watch(updateList);

      function updateList() {
         scope.weeks = sortItems(parseItems(scope.master));
      }

      function sortItems(sets) {
        var items = [];
        // get a list of weeks and sort them
        var weeks = sortDescending(Object.keys(sets));
         for(var i=0, wlen=weeks.length; i < wlen; i++) {
           var w = weeks[i];
           // get a list of days and sort them
           var days = sortDescending(Object.keys(sets[w]));
           var weekEntry = {
             time: w,
             days: []
           };
           items.push(weekEntry);
           // now iterate the days and add entries
           for(var j=0, dlen=days.length; j < dlen; j++) {
             var d = days[j];
             weekEntry.days.push({
               time: d,
               // here is the list of tasks from parseItems
               items: sets[w][d]
             });
           }
         }
         console.log('sortItems', items);
         return items;
      }

      // take the array and nest it in an object by week and then day
      function parseItems(master) {
        var sets = {};
        angular.forEach(master, function(item) {
           var week = moment(item.$priority).startOf('week').valueOf();
           var day = moment(item.$priority).startOf('day').valueOf();
           if( !sets.hasOwnProperty(week) ) {
             sets[week] = {};
           }
           if( !sets[week].hasOwnProperty(day) ) {
             sets[week][day] = [];

           }
           sets[week][day].push(item);
         });
         console.log('parseItems', sets);
         return sets;
      }

      function sortDescending(list) {
        return list.sort().reverse();
      }

    }
  };
});
```

How can I access the $scope.update, delete, and complete functions from the controller inside of the repeat.html file (or move the repeat.html file into index.html if that allows me to access those functions).

Comment: Have you tried `$scope.$parent.update()` to see if it's an isolated scope problem.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any effect. $scope.$parent.updateTask...

Comment: If you're using Chrome. You can inspect the scope by selecting a DOM element, then in the console type `$($0).scope()`.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is isolate scope.There is a problem of separation of concerns here. Your directive is tightly coupled with the controller. You should really create a service that performs the operations instead of placing everything in the controller. And  either you should have a function binding on your directive for the actions that it's consumer can use or your directive should be self container to perform deletion on its own. You are trying to work around that.

Comment: $($0).scope() returns undefined. @MathewFoscarini

Comment: If I create a service to handle the $scope functions will I be able to trigger those functions even though they would come from repeat.html?

Comment: Right click and select "inspect element". In the "elements" tab select the HTML dom that contains a ng-snope or ng-isolate-scope CSS class. Then try `$($0).scope()`. The `$0` refers to Chrome's currently selected DOM element.

Comment: Check this out. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api

Comment: I'm going to up-vote this question, not because I think that it deserves an up-vote, but because I think that the down-vote is a bit too much: binding functions with an isolated scope directive is not super straightforward, specially when the bound functions are using parameters. The Angular guide for example (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) doesn't explain how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have an isolated scope, so you may as well just bind the functions that you need from the controller, you can do it like this (showing only the relevant code for the different parts):

Inside Index.html:

```
<repeat-by-week collection="list" update-task='updateTask(task)' delete-task='deleteTask(task)' is-complete-task='isCompleteTask(task)' ></repeat-by-week>
```

Inside your directive:

```
scope: {
  'master': '=collection',
  'deleteTask': '&',
  'isCompleteTask': '&',
  'updateTask': '&'
}
```

Inside repeat.html:

```
      <li ng-repeat="task in day.items">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.complete" ng-change="isCompleteTask({task:task})">
        <input ng-model="task.title" ng-change="updateTask({task:task})">
        <button ng-click="deleteTask({task:task})">x</button>
      </li>
```

### [Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/XnNqej?p=preview)

Comment: Would this be necessary if I did a transclude instead? Is a transclude much more difficult to achieve in this case? I can't seem to find a course (paid or free) that covers my specific case or explains it enough that I am able to do it.

Comment: @PSL Wow! I wasn't reading the comments of the question, I can't believe that I got a correct answer before you... You must tired or something ;) Thanks for the edit!

Comment: @EmptyPockets sorry, I don't get it, why would you want to transclude in a directive like this?

Comment: @Josep I'm going to need similar but slightly modified code throughout this app so I want to be able to re-use this directive but modify some of the sorting and display functionality. Also, it would be nice if I didn't have to have a separate file and could have the repeating list inside of index.html. Also, I very likely don't understand the pros/cons of transclude so I might be looking for something else.

Comment: @PSL oh! I see, it was just a joke, I'm sure that you would have been able to solve this in your sleep.

Comment: For example, I need to use this directive on the same page twice, both use the same list but one does not have a checkbox or edit options. Should I use ng-show/hide to modify the list based on where it's located? Should I make a new post about this? (After exploring on my own for some more time).

Comment: @EmptyPockets it sounds like you want your directive to have a boolean property in its scope that would act as an "editable" flag or something like that, and if that flag is set to true you show and use the options for editing and if not then those options are either hidden or disabled. You could just use the same directive and inside the controller of the directive check if the bound functions are undefined and if they are undefined just set that attribute to false, otherwise true... I don't see how transcluding could be even related with all this.

Comment: @Josep Thank you again. Sorry for pushing this transclude thing, this solution works and I am very thankful for all of your help. I generally wanted transclude for unimportant reasons. It seems like with transclude I don't need to pass in individual scopes and would have access to the full controller scope (maybe that's not how it works). I also thought it would be nice to not have a separate file for repeat.html and instead put the content of repeat.html inside of <repeat-by-week/>. I'm going to stick with this for now and see if I can get everything I need to work.